# jquery datatables hide sort arrows and remove the padding but keep functionality

Tags: datatables

I would like to remove the sort arrows with the padding on jquery datatables. I have tried the examples here but it is not exactly what i am after

[Sort arrows in datatables to be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287390/sort-arrows-in-datatables-to-be-removed)

I tried added the followign which only hides the icons but not the padding

```
.dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*="sort"]:after{
    content: "" !important;
}
```

I tried adding `$(".sorting").removeClass("sorting")`; but this messes up the column widths. When I click on column to sort it adds the padding on and the headers become not aligned with the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For jQuery DataTables 1.10+ with Bootstrap styling, use the following CSS rules:

```
.dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*="sort"]:after{
    content: "" !important;
}

table.dataTable thead > tr > th.sorting_asc, 
table.dataTable thead > tr > th.sorting_desc, 
table.dataTable thead > tr > th.sorting, 
table.dataTable thead > tr > td.sorting_asc, 
table.dataTable thead > tr > td.sorting_desc, 
table.dataTable thead > tr > td.sorting {
    padding-right: inherit;
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wh2f41c/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: your 2nd style didnt work for me i had to do `table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting_asc, table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting_desc, table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting, table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting_asc, table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting_desc, table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting{
 padding-right: inherit;
 
}`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using `table-sm` with Bootstrap 4:

```
.dataTable > thead > tr > th[class*="sort"]:after{
    content: "" !important;
}

table.dataTable.table-sm>thead>tr>th { 
    padding-right: inherit !important; 
}
```